# How to update a JSP page html element using ceratin Javascript logic?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a JSP page called `root.jsp`, in that i have a footer tag which displaces certain text( that is coming from a properties file from java end). The footer tag itself is displayed using scriplets based on certain roles that is logged in to the Site. `root.jsp` has `global.js` file included here is the code snippet

```
**root.jsp**   
 <%if(role.equals("Learner")){%>
        <footer>
            <p id ="par1">${userAccessMsg}.</p>
            <p id ="par2">${userNoFolderAccessMsg}.</p>
        </footer>
        <%} %>
```

I need to display only one `<p>` tag by checking if the variable `folders` is empty or not .

```
 **global.js**
    var folders = getConfigLinkedFolders();
    function getConfigLinkedFolders {
       return arrayList; /*["defssfsf","hrhrhhr"] */
}
```

How should i do this?

Comment: please don't use scriptlets! read about [JSTL core](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a method in the DOM ready handler where in you can add a class to the element in question.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var folders = getConfigLinkedFolders();

     if(folders && folders.length > 0) {
          $('#par2').addClass('hide');
     } else {
          $('#par1').addClass('hide');
     }
});

function getConfigLinkedFolders {
    return arrayList; /*["defssfsf","hrhrhhr"] */
}
```

And in your CSS file define the class `hide`

```
.hide {
    display : none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. i have a question. IN root.jsp i have added the $(document).ready() and added the above showed code. In the root.jsp i have a certain section is displayed from different jsp page say section.jsp. in that section.jsp have another. $(document).ready() function. IS this good way of doing this? nothing is broke after added the code of yours. just want to be sure this is still valid implementation

Comment: @pushya .. It is always a better idea to have the class assigned in the jsp page itself instead of writing javascript for such cases, where in just accessing the `DOM` , the user can remove the class and see the info underneath..